# Easy Ribbon with two GroupDefinitions

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I'm using the Easy Ribbon API to show Ribbons in Edit/Disp form.
When I only use one GroupDefinition everything works like a charm, but as soon as I want to add a second group of ribbons, the first one disappears and only the second one is shown.

```
        //Code sample first group
        var ribbonCustomAction = new RibbonCustomAction();
        var notificationButtonDefinition = new ButtonDefinition()
        {
            Id = "Doc_erzeugen",
            Title = "Dokument erzeugen",
            CommandJavaScript = "createDocument();",
            Image = ImageLibrary.GetStandardImage(2, 1, web.CurrencyLocaleID)
        };
        var actionGroupDefinition2 = new GroupDefinition()
        {
            Id = "Process_Actions",
            Title = "Dokument Aktionen",
            Template = GroupTemplateLibrary.SimpleTemplate,
            Controls = new ControlDefinition[]
            {
                notificationButtonDefinition
            }
        };
        ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition2, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Display.Id, 3005);
        ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition2, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Edit.Id, 3005);
        ribbonCustomAction.Provision(ReceiverGuid, list);
```

If I use this code only, it shows the expected ribbons.

[image: RibbonBar1]

```
        //Code sample second group
        var ribbonCustomAction = new RibbonCustomAction();
        var notificationButtonDefinition = new ButtonDefinition()
        {
            Id = "Doc_erzeugen",
            Title = "Dokument erzeugen",
            CommandJavaScript = "createDocument();",
            Image = ImageLibrary.GetStandardImage(2, 1, web.CurrencyLocaleID)
        };

                    var actionGroupDefinition2 = new GroupDefinition()
        {
            Id = "Process_Actions",
            Title = "Vorgang Aktionen",
            Template = GroupTemplateLibrary.SimpleTemplate,
            Controls = new ControlDefinition[]
            {
                createAppointmentButtonDefinition
            }
        };
        ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition2, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Display.Id, 3002);
        ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition2, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Edit.Id, 3002);
        ribbonCustomAction.Provision(ReceiverGuid, ToolkitUtility.FindListByName(web, "Vorgänge"));
```

But after adding this code, all I get is this.

[image: RibbonBar2]

Also the Ribbons are shown in the NewForm which they shouldn't...

Comment: [Easy Ribbon API](https://easyribbon.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake...

The sequence (`AddControlGroup([..], [..], Sequence)`)has to be the same value in each form.
So for my example that'd be:

```
   ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition1, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Display.Id, 3002);
   ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition1, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Edit.Id, 3003);

    ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition2, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Display.Id, 3002);
    ribbonCustomAction.AddControlGroup(actionGroupDefinition2, SPRibbonIds.ListForm_Edit.Id, 3003);
```

The new form "problem" was solved by hiding via JQuerys `.hide()`